# Spring Boot 2.0.3 Oauth2 Security: Getting 401 error even when using access token in header

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, http-status-code-401

I'm creating a spring boot 2.0 application and trying to enable oauth2 security. I have Auth server and Resource server in the same application as of now. My client and user details as well as token generated are persisted in databases (mysql) and database schema is the same as provided by spring documentation. When I hit the '/oauth/token/' endpoint providing clientId and clientSecret in header and user's credentials in body using Postman, I'm getting access token successfully.

```
{
"access_token": "bef2d974-2e7d-4bf0-849d-d80e8021dc50",
"token_type": "bearer",
"refresh_token": "32ed6252-e7ee-442c-b6f9-d83b0511fcff",
"expires_in": 6345,
"scope": "read write trust"
}
```

But when I try to hit my rest api using this access token, I'm getting 401 Unauthorized error:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-08-13T11:17:19.813+0000",
"status": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"path": "/myapp/api/unsecure"
}
```

The rest APIs I'm hitting are as follows:

http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/unsecure

http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/secure

myapp is the context path of my application.

For 'secure' api, I have provided access token in request header as described in Spring documentation:

```
Authorization: Bearer bef2d974-2e7d-4bf0-849d-d80e8021dc50
```

Whereas for unsecure api, I have tried with and without Authentication header. In all cases I'm getting same error for both apis.

Also when I try to print currently authenticated user, its getting printed as anonymousUser.

**What I want are as follows:**

1) I want my secure api to be accessible only when access token is provided in request header.

2) I want my unsecure api to be accessible by unauthorised user.

3) I should get currently authenticated user using SecurityContextHolder when accessing secure url.

**My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is as follows:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
}

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
Exception {
    auth
    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
    .passwordEncoder(userPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws 
Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore 
tokenStore){
    TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new 
    TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
    handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
    handler.setRequestFactory(new 
    DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
    handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    return handler;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws 
Exception {
    TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
    store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
    return store;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .cors().disable()
    .anonymous().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/index.html", "/**.js", "/**.css", "/").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
}
```

Here using antMatchers I have permitted static pages of Angular 6 application, as I'm planning to use those in my real app. And no, the following line does not work to allow static pages of angular application:

```
.requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
```

**My AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter is as follows:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
TokenStore tokenStore;

@Autowired
private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
    oauthServer
    .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
    .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dataSource);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints
    .tokenStore(tokenStore)
    .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
}
```

**My ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter is as follows:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public abstract class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource-server-rest-api";

@Autowired
TokenStore tokenStore;

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources
    .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
    .tokenStore(tokenStore);
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .cors().disable()
    .anonymous().disable()
    .requestMatchers()
    .antMatchers("/api/**").and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/secure").authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/api/unsecure").permitAll();
}
}
```

But when I enable anonymous access in SecurityConfig and declare my unsecure url as permitAll, then I'm able to access that url.

```
.antMatchers("/api/unsecure", "/index.html", "/**.js", "/**.css", "/").permitAll()
```

**My Controller class is as follows:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DemoController {

@GetMapping("/secure")
public void sayHelloFriend() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println("Current User: "+authentication.getName());
    System.out.println("Hello Friend");
}

@GetMapping("/unsecure")
public void sayHelloStranger() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println("Current User: "+authentication.getName());
    System.out.println("Hello Stranger");
}
}
```

Let me know if any more information is needed. Any help will be appreciated. **But please keep in mind that its Spring Boot 2.0 not 1.5 as both have some critical differences as per my findings.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to added

```
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
```

for the securityConfig? so the chain will check your Resource server's config first.

And not sure if that your type error, remove the abstract from the resource server.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Niuhuru Lang. It was actually the abstract keyword in ResourceServerConfig that was messing with my code. Don't know how it got there. Silly me!!

Comment: @AdityaKumar would you exactly mention where the `@Order` is in your code